# I want to make an intent to the settings menu, without showing any activity while coming back

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, settings

The code is working and  opens the data roaming setting when app opens , but when I click on back button it is showing an empty activity, which I don't want it to display. I want that when I click on that back button ,I should reach back to the previous task.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Which task ? and what blank activity you are seeing add screen shot

Comment: it works very well for me specify the device and os version

Comment: but now when I open the app, while opening it is showing a glimpse of the activity created, I also don't want this glimpse. Can you sort it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finish the activity as soon as firing the intent using

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); // Will destroy the activity and remove from stack
}
```

Comment: but now when I open the app, while opening it is showing a glimpse of the activity created, I also don't want this glimpse. Can you sort it out?

Comment: You can set the theme `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` for you activity in Manifest. But this theme will not work for AppCompatActivity (Support library). Extend your class to `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`. This is just a hack to make the activity invisible. The app still is visible on screen "Invisibly" until `finish()` is called